# Javascript; Adding text on image using canvas and save to image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i just want to make a page where u can type a text and add it on selected image and save that as new image.

I tried to do it in few ways, but without luck.

```
<body>
<canvas id = "idCanvas" width = "576" height = "577"> </canvas>
<img id="canvasImg" width = "576" height = "577"></img>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('idCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 576, 577);
    context.font = "20px Calibri";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 50, 200);

    document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = toDataURL();
    window.alert(dataURL);
  };
  imageObj.src =  "image.png";

  };



</script>
```

When i use toDataURL() in img src, the image won't be displayed, it only works if i'm not using drawImage in canvas.

Comment: Question, where does the toDataURL() comes from ?

Comment: my bad, i meant `document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL`,

Answer (score 3):

Ok so yes it will not work for security reason, but there is a solution.
See here a working demo: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/arL9wfux/)

```
draw();

function draw() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('idCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imageObj = new Image();


  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    context.font = "40px Calibri";
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 50, 300);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('idCanvas');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    alert(dataURL);
  }
imageObj.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
imageObj.src = "https://loremflickr.com/400/200";
};
```

Comment: The image url needs to be changed when you look at the fiddle. There is a cross-site problem.

Comment: @BradenBrown Thnx. Fixed it with different link. Still a warning from jsfiddle itself but the image loads.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Should it be **canvas**.toDataURL() ?

Here is a similar example with getting contents into image element http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Also I was getting the following error when image is loaded from another hostname:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

When image is not added to canvas it works fine, so issue could be related to [CORS HTTP headers not added with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027839/todataurl-throw-uncaught-security-exception). Try removing

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 576, 577);
```

to see that it works without image

Here is a demo based on code in question. 
http://jsbin.com/logikuwefo/1/edit